# MultiValueDictKeyError when click the submit button but not choose any file, using Django

Tags: python, html, django, file-upload

I made an input on the HTML File and the HTML code is

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{%csrf_token%}
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <input type="file" name="document"/>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <center>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
  </center>
</form>
```

and my views.py is

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    file_exist = request.POST.get('document')
    fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
    # --- my another stuff ---
else:
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I made a code like that and when running a server that is no problem until I click the submit button by not choose any file (no file is chosen) and I have got an error

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /creative/
>   'document'
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/creative/
>   Django Version: 2.2.12
>   Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
>   Exception Value:
>   'document'
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\User\Envs\pp\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in **getitem**, line 80
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\User\Envs\pp\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.5.5
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\User\Desktop\crrnt wrk\Perfect Pitch\PerfectPitch',
>    'C:\Users\User\Envs\pp\Scripts\python35.zip',
>    'c:\programdata\anaconda3\DLLs',
>    'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib',
>    'c:\programdata\anaconda3',
>    'C:\Users\User\Envs\pp',
>    'C:\Users\User\Envs\pp\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time:    Tue, 19 May 2020 08:55:22 +0000

so how should I solve this problem? Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Problem:D I just use the Try-Except Block.
Maybe this can help you

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
              uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
              fs = FileSystemStorage()
              file_exist = request.POST.get('document')
              fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
              # --- my another stuff ---

        except Exception:
           #use pass or a logger info or something else
```

So now, if u press the submit button ur programm will not crash and if u input a file, everything works fine too. Hope this can help u!